# How to get only the Time from DateTime datatype

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have a table called `TimeSpan`.  It contains a column `StartTime`.  `StartTime` is of type `DateTime`.  In my view I pass a time.  Therefore, I need to convert `StartTime` to `time("HH:mm")`.  How can I accomplish that?

```
public ActionResult planview(Double budget, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    var model = from Ts in db.TimeSpans 
                where Ts.StartTime < startTime 
                select Ts;
    return View(model);
}
```

The above query needs to be changed to `Ts.StartTime(convert to time) < startTime`.

Comment: So you need to return an IEnumerable which contains all the times?

Comment: yes...I want to display them all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>You can use [DateTime.TimeOfDay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx)</del>

<del>var model = from Ts in db.TimeSpans</del> 
               <del>where Ts.StartTime.TimeOfDay < startTime</del> 
               <del>select Ts;</del>

**Edit** based on comments, you can use [EntityFunctions.CreateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.createtime(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var model = from Ts in db.TimeSpans 
            let time = EntityFunctions.CreateTime(Ts.StartTime.Hours,
                                                  Ts.StartTime.Minutes,
                                                  Ts.StartTime.Seconds)
            where time < startTime 
            select Ts;
```

Comment: This gives an exception!!!!!
The specified type member 'TimeOfDay' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Answer (score 4):

The time portion of a DateTime object is returned as a `TimeSpan` by the [TimeOfDay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

You don't have to extract the time portion though, if all you want is to format the value for display. You can simply specify the appropriate format string when rendering your view.

The time portion of a DateTime object is return as a TimeSpan by the [TimeOfDay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

You don't have to extract the time portion though, if all you want is to format the value for display. You can simply specify the appropriate format string when rendering your view, eg:

```
@Model.StartTime.ToString("hh:mm")
```